# How can I create an Array of fitted PipelineModelS in Spark 2.1.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, decision-tree, multiclass-classification

I am trying to store a `PipelineModel` of each trained Decision Tree model into an `Array`. Although I created an array of `PipelineModelS` I have the following mismatch error:

```
<console>:96: error: type mismatch;
found   : model.type (with underlying type org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel)
required: org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel.type
           bestModels(i) = model // Here is the problem!!!
```

Can anyone help me please? The dataset of *iris flowers* (in **libsvm** format) can be found here https://1drv.ms/u/s!Antm9EMPXrQmgP9zQhgdAdxUBSAtSA. This is the example code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassifier
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{IndexToString, StringIndexer, VectorIndexer}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val folds = 10
val data =  spark.read.format("libsvm").load("/home/vitrion/Documents/iris.libsvm")
var accuracies = Array.fill(folds)(0.0)
var bestModels = Array.fill(folds)(PipelineModel) // This is the array of PipelineModelS

val Array(trainData, testData) = data.orderBy(rand()).randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3), seed = 1234L)
val foldedData = trainData.orderBy(rand()).randomSplit(Array.fill(10)(1.0 / folds))
val evaluator1 = new MulticlassClassificationEvaluator().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setPredictionCol("prediction").setMetricName("accuracy")

for( i <- 0 to folds - 1 ){
    var provTrainData = data.limit(0)
    var provTestData = data.limit(0)
    var foldStr = ""
    for( j <- 0 to folds - 1){
        var str = ""
        if (i != j) {
            provTrainData = provTrainData.union(foldedData(j))
            str = "T"
        } else {
            provTestData = foldedData(i)
            str = "S"
        }
        foldStr += str
    }
    println(foldStr)
    val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("label").setOutputCol("indexedLabel").fit(trainData)
    val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("indexedFeatures").setMaxCategories(6).fit(trainData)
    val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier().setLabelCol("indexedLabel").setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures")
    val labelConverter = new IndexToString().setInputCol("prediction").setOutputCol("predictedLabel").setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureIndexer, dt, labelConverter))            
    val model = pipeline.fit(provTrainData)

    var provPredictions = model.transform(provTestData)
    accuracies(i) = evaluator1.evaluate(provPredictions)
    bestModels(i) = model // Here is the problem!!!
    println("FOLD " + i + "\nAccuracy: " + accuracies(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct problem is that:

```
Array.fill(folds)(PipelineModel)
```

create an `Array[PipelineModel.type]`, not `Array[PipelineModel]`. You can either:

```
val bestModels: Array[PipelineModel] = Array.ofDim[PipelineModel](folds)
```

or:

```
val bestModels: Array[PipelineModel] = Array.fill(folds)(null)
```

On a side not there is no need for `var` here. Since you mutable object, `val` will do just fine.

Moreover `Pipeline` definition could be simplified to:

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
  .setHandleInvalid("skip")
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(labelIndexer, dt))
```

or even `DecisionTreeClassifier` alone (with adjusted `evaluator.labelCol`):

```
val dt = new DecisionTreeClassifier()
  .setLabelCol("label")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")

// No need for pipeline here
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(Array(dt))
```

and pulled out of the loop.

Note that you should provide a strategy to handle unseen labels for `StringIndexer`, especially with small dataset like this.

Since iris dataset doesn't contain categorical features `VectorIndexer` is obsolete and `DecisionTreeClassifier` should handle numerical labels with consecutive values without indexing (at least in Spark 2.0 and later).

Finally the loop can be simplified to

```
val (models, accuracies) = (0 until folds).map { fold => {
  val train = foldedData.patch(fold, Nil, 1).reduce(_ union _)
  val test = foldedData(fold)
  val model = pipeline.fit(train)
  val predictions = model.transform(test)
  (model, evaluator1.evaluate(predictions))
}}.unzip
```

If you really want all the preprocessing steps with indexing and encoding it would make more sense to apply it once.